# Скролл на Android

Tags: эмулятор, android, html, css

Я хочу сделать скролл на Android? В css задал

```
 overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;

        <li><p>Balkon</p><div><input/></div></li>
        <li><p>Badkamer</p><div><input/></div></li>
        <li><p>Matercast</p><div><input/></div></li>
        .....
```

Проблема в том, что на эмуляторе этого скролла нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этого нету не только на эмуляторе но и на девайсе. WebView не поддерживает скролы у вложенных дивов, надо извращаться на js:
можно попробовать что то типа http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/
можно глянуть в сторону фонегапа и поискать там фреймворк для скроллов (http://phonegap.com/)